# - A Devil's Lie -

Tags: story, crossword-clues, printers-devilry

The printer's devil came into our office last night.
But today he said:

> 1. I am no evil (3)
> 2. I never E ards (3)
> 3. Ion LT fruits and vegetables (3)
> 4. I did ner your room. (4)
> 5. I didn't, Ouch, your door. (5)
> 6. I am no cent (2)
> 7. It the truth just now (3)

Can you find the missing words?

Note: This is my first attempt at crossword clues, so please give feedback.
Note: Some clues *may* have multiple answers.
Note: Do not ignore any of the tags.

Comment: Any chance we can get an update on this? It's been a few days and I don't think anyone knows whether my answer is correct or incorrect.

Answer (score 6):

> i am noT A Devil // i never eaT WOrds // i onlY EAt fruits and vegetables // i didn'T ENTer your room // i didn't EVER (or EVEN) Touch your door // i am INnocent // i tOLD the truth just now

edited - thanks to @jafe for the alternative suggestion on #4.

Comment: #4 could be rot13(rirag) as well.

Comment: agreed! that is probably the intended solution, but i guess it's a good lesson for the creator - it's important not to have multiple equally valid solutions.

Comment: @jafe Please do not ignore the "story" tag.

Comment: It doesn't look to me as if hdsdv has ignored the [story] tag -- the answer here links with the (tiny) story contained in the original question, and maintains a thread of continuity within its resolutions of the seven clues.

Comment: (@Scratch---Cat)  I agree with GarethMcCaughan.  In addition, if this is NOT the answer, the question is likely *too broad*. There's no reason I can think of why this isn't a fully valid solution, and where multiple answers could fit, the puzzle is under-specified. A well-crafted puzzle will give enough information to rule in the intended solution while ruling out everything else.